# GLAD #defines hidden behind #ifndef GL_VERSION_X_X, using Visual Studio 2022

Tags: c++, opengl, sdl, preprocessor, glad

I have started learning engine development and have decided to use GLAD and SDL2 for my project. I have followed various tutorials and have successfully linked both SDL2 and GLAD to my project. But I have encountered a very strange problem.

I tried to use the `glGenBuffers()` function but Visual Studio told me `glGenBuffers is undefined`. So I went into the glad.h and searched for `glGenBuffers` and found it inside of `#ifndef GL_VERSION_1_5`. (I could not use any other functions as well.)

So I tried to comment out the `#ifndef` and `#endif` for that part and now it worked! I could use `glGenBuffers`. And beacuse I know I have version 4.6 of opengl I don't have to worry about the versions.

The problem here is that this feels like I am not doing it like it's supposed to, and that this might introduce problems in the future. So what I did was I put the `#ifndef` and `#endif` back into it's place. But now the glad.h was absolutely littered with multiple errors of these types:

```
this declaration has no storage class or type specifier
the #if for this directive is missing
the #endif for this directive is missing
```

The document was exactly the same as when I got it, but what was even more strange was that now every other function worked as well. Even those not in the `#ifndef GL_VERSION_1_5` but for example `#ifndef GL_VERSION_3_0`.

And the code in the main.cpp still compiled and ran fine. When I collapse the `#ifndef GL_VERSION_1_5` it now says "Active Preprocessor Block" as well, wheras the others say "Inactive Preprocessor Block".

I tried replacing the document with another copy and now I am back to the old problem of it stating `glGenBuffers is undefined`. It's worth noting `gladLoadGLLoader(( GLADloadproc )SDL_GL_GetProcAddress)` works fine at runtime so it's not a problem with GLAD itself.

Anyone know what might be causing this and how I should go about solving this problem?

The includes I'm currently using:

```cpp
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL_opengl.h>
#include <glad/glad.h>
```

Compile log:

```
Build started...
1>------ Build started: Project: GrubEngineC++, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>GrubEngineC++.cpp
1>C:\Users\Arbeit\Desktop\C++ Engine\GEC\GrubEngineC++\include\glad\glad.h(873,1): warning C4005: 'GL_INVALID_INDEX': macro redefinition
1>C:\Users\Arbeit\Desktop\C++ Engine\GEC\SDL2\include\SDL_opengl_glext.h(1651): message : see previous definition of 'GL_INVALID_INDEX'
1>C:\Users\Arbeit\Desktop\C++ Engine\GEC\GrubEngineC++\include\glad\glad.h(915,1): warning C4005: 'GL_TIMEOUT_IGNORED': macro redefinition
1>C:\Users\Arbeit\Desktop\C++ Engine\GEC\SDL2\include\SDL_opengl_glext.h(1726): message : see previous definition of 'GL_TIMEOUT_IGNORED'
1>C:\Users\Arbeit\Desktop\C++ Engine\GEC\GrubEngineC++\GrubEngineC++.cpp(15,5): error C3861: 'glGenBuffers': identifier not found
1>Done building project "GrubEngineC++.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: `#ifndef GL_VERSION_1_5` is a header guard and prevents you from getting into troubles when glad.h is included in multiple places. Unless you defined `GL_VERSION_1_5` in your code, the content of the `#ifndef` block will be present. Are you sure that you actually get compile errors (and not just IntelliSense errors)? If so, please add the compile log from the output window and the exact error messages.

Comment: I added the output of the project when I try to use glGenBuffers();
I hope this is the correct log @BDL

Comment: The warnings before the error also look very suspicious. There seems to be a definition for `GL_INVALID_INDEX` somewhere before the include of glad.h (which shouldn't be the case). Do you include any other libraries/headerfiles/... that contain OpenGL definitions? Or do you include `SDL_opengl.h` before glad? If that's not the case, could you provide a minimal code example where you get the error?

Comment: I included `SDL_opengl.h` before glad. Changing the inclusion order solved the issue! To think that it was that simple this whole time! Thanks for the help. If you could post your comment as an answer I accept it. (Don't really now how stack overflow deals with comments haha) @BDL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the include order for the OpenGL definitions. As can be seen in the compile log, there are also other definitions like `GL_INVALID_INDEX` that are already defined when glad is included.

The `SDL_opengl.h` is the OpenGL header for SDL and already contains the definitions for a lot of the OpenGL related symbols and conflicts with the use of `glad.h`. You either have to include it after `glad.h` or not all (which is better, unless you need methods from `SDL_opengl.h`.